# Model.objects.filter([foreign table]).update()

Tags: python, django

How can I change `[book must etc...]` with real Django code in this scenario:

```
Book.objects.filter(processed=True, [book must have all the volumes belonging to it with property is_file_processed set to True]).update(status="PU")
```

Models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    ...


class Volume(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(...)
    ...
    is_file_processed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that the set of all books having all volumes processed equals to the result that the set of all books having at least one volume processed subtracts the set of all books having unprocessed volumes:

```
Book.objects.filter(processed=True, volume__is_file_processed=True).exclude(volume__is_file_processed=False).update(status="PU")
# Or    
Book.objects.exclude(volume__is_file_processed=False).filter(processed=True, volume__is_file_processed=True).update(status="PU")
```

Answer (score 1):

See that [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). I think that could work.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    ...


class Volume(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(...)
    ...
    is_file_processed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='volumes')

Book.objects.filter(processed=True, volumes__is_file_processed=True).update(status="PU")
```